# Hi need to know the correct usage of 'set of.....'

Tags: plural-forms, grammatical-number

Which is the correct line

> Set of 3 cushion cover

or

> Set of 3 cushion covers

Comment: How many sets (of 3 cushion covers) would you like to buy? ;-)

Answer (score 3):

None!

What would be correct is -

> ***A*** set of 3 cushion ***covers***

The word 'set' is a noun and would require an article. If the *set* is already introduced or if there's only one set right there, it'd take ***'the'***. But that's an all different question.

`A set of something` takes plural; because 'set' is more than one thing in such context.  Said that...

> *a set of napkins* 
>  *a set of coins*, and so on...

Answer (score -1):

> Set of 3 cushion covers

The reason being is that although "set" is singular, "3" is describing the number of cushion covers, which is plural in this case. If it is still unclear, remove "set of" and you can see that "3 cushion cover" does not sound grammatically correct.

Comment: Set is not a mass noun and it would require an article.